# python os.sys.stdin.buffer.read failed if given buffer length

Tags: python, windows, python-3.3

```
import os
s = os.sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024*32)
```

failed with

```
D:\Projects\pytools>python t1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = os.sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024*32)
OSError: [Errno 12] Not enough space
```

buf if given buflen = 1024*32-1 then it goes right

```
import os
s = os.sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024*32-1)
```

if you run python t1.py, then the process blocked and waiting for input as expect.
Why python3.3 have 1024*32-1 buffer length limitation? Is it system different, or just a the same for all systems? How can we remove this limitation?

BTW: i using windows 7 python 32 bit version 3.3

Comment: Don't see any errors on Linux 64bit until I increase it to `1024**3 * 6`, then I get a `MemoryError`.

Comment: The same problem on my Win7+Python3.3.0-32bit. But if I run the script in Cygwin Python 2.7.3, it runs perfectly. Upgrading to 3.3.1 doesn't help.

Comment: I've tried 32-bit Python 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 2.7.4 and 64-bit 3.31, but all have the same problem. It seems to be a Windows-port-specific issue. You might try asking this question on Python mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

We start by looking at the source of `os` module [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9893d13c628/Lib/os.py), where line 26 reads
`import sys, errno`
This tells us that `os.sys` is just a reference to the standard `sys` module.
Then we head over to the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9893d13c628/Python/sysmodule.c) of the `sys` module, where in line 1593 we find the following comment (thankfully someone put it there...):
`/* stdin/stdout/stderr are now set by pythonrun.c */`
Then we go to the `pythonrun.c` [file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9893d13c628/Python/pythonrun.c), where we meet the following code in line 1086:
`std = create_stdio(iomod, fd, 0, "<stdin>", encoding, errors);`
and this on line 1091:
`PySys_SetObject("stdin", std);`
Then we look for definition of `create_stdio()` function which we find in line 910. We look for the return value of this function which is on line 999 and looks like this:
`return stream;`
Now we have to find out what the `stream` is. It's the return value of function `_PyObject_CallMethodId()` called in line 984.

I hope you see the flow - try to follow from here.